# Looping by 2 index of char

Tags: java, arraylist

Please I need help to loop into an ArrayList :

> [PR, PS, QS, QT, RP, RT, SP, SQ, TQ, TR]

So that my output be like this :

```
1) PR PS
2) QS QT
3) RP RT 
4) SP SQ 
5) TQ TR
```

Notice that once I read the first 2 , i am jumping to the third an fourth index;
Thank you beloved community of Stack

Comment: Yeah go for it!

Comment: Lol, well if you have some to share bro ?

Comment: Please post code what you have tried till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this simple code

```
    String [] arr = {"PR", "PS", "QS", "QT", "RP", "RT", "SP", "SQ", "TQ", "TR"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i = i + 2) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s %n", list.get(i), list.get(i + 1));
    }
```

or if you want the numbering

```
System.out.printf("%d) %s %s %n", (i / 2) + 1, list.get(i), list.get(i + 1));
```

Comment: nice but you should use %n instead of \n in your printf.

Comment: Thank you my friend, it is working ; i just needed this kind of loop

Comment: `for (int i=0;i<list.size();i=i+2){
   System.out.printf("%s %s %n", list.get(i), list.get(i+1));
  }`  
the above worked for me, so i m just worndering why u are using -1 with list.size as it anyway having "<". Can u please look once.

Comment: @dildeepak Thanks for your comment, both are good, but I thought that my way re-enforces the intention

Answer (score 0):

The @Scary Wombat solution is great, but what if you will had an odd size of the array? Suppose you will have one more value, XY at the end of the list, the output should be:

> TR XY

i think it's a good idea to take care of the odd case, my solution would be:

```
        List<String> array = Arrays.asList("PR", "PS", "QS", "QT", "RP", "RT", "SP", "SQ", "TQ", "TR", "XY");
        for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
                if (i%2==1 || i == array.size()-1) {
                        System.out.println(array.get(i-1)+", "+array.get(i));
                }
        }
```

The below code would cause the next output:

```
PR, PS
QS, QT
RP, RT
SP, SQ
TQ, TR
TR, XY
```